# Whitelist nginx proxy_pass $args

Tags: nginx, proxypass, whitelist

I have nginx configured to proxy requests :

```
server  {
    listen      80;
    server_name proxy.mydomain.com;

    location /proxy {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass $args/;
    }
}
```

So I can make request like : http://proxy.mydomain.com/proxy?http://www.test.com

I'd like to control which domain is allowed to be proxied. I don't know how to do it without an ***if***.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without `if`? Sometimes it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I use `/` instead of `?`, to proxy to `www.test.com/xyz`, it would be `http://proxy.mydomain.com/proxy/www.test.com/xyz`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxy.mydomain.com;

    location ~ ^/proxy/(?<proxy_host>[^/]+)/(?<proxy_path>.+)$ {
        proxy_pass http://$proxy_host/$proxy_path?$args;
    }
}
```